# How can I overlay a larger watermark/frame image on a smaller one?

Tags: imagemagick

I have an overlay image, which is like a watermark/logo, which needs to be overlayed on top of the source image (while preserving alpha channel, etc)

When overlay is the same or smaller dimension as the source image - things are easy:

```
composite.exe -alpha on -gravity center logo.png in_image.jpg out_image.jpg
```

However, when logo.png is larger than in_image.jpg - above call truncates the logo, and out_image.jpg has the same dimensions as in_image.jpg

I would like the resulting image to be the largest of either the logo.png or in_image.jpg so I can do things like artistic frames around the photos.

Below image demonstrates the end result I want to be able to get this:
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChHop.jpg)

Note, here, the png with skulls has larger dims than the kiddo's image. The alpha channel needs to be preserved.

Edit: more clarity through examples

Here is another [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyT6u.jpg)
Here, the png file is opaque on the sides, has a clear window in the middle, and half-translucent bubbles. the JPG file is just a regular JPG from a camera.

Would love to add original and logo files that result in it, but lack reputation to add more than 2 links (or to add images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you have v7 of **ImageMagick**, you can get it to do the maths for you all in one line using `-fx` to determine the dimensions of the larger of the two images:

```
magick background.jpg overlay.png -background none -gravity center -extent '%[fx:u.w>v.w?u.w:v.w]x%[fx:u.h>v.h?u.h:v.h]' -composite result.png
```

That basically says... *"Extend the two images as follows. If the width of the first image (`u.w`) is greater than that of the second image (`v.w`), then use the width of the first, else use that of the second. Same for height."*.

**Original Answer**

I believe you want this. Get width of whatever is wider of background and overlay. Get height of whatever is taller of background and overlay. Extend both background and overlay with transparent pixels to new dimensions. Overlay.

So, if we start with this as background (300x50):

[image]

And this as overlay (122x242) - which is a tall blue rectangle surrounded with transparency then that is bordered in black to show the extent of it:

[image]

You would run this, which is actually very simple but it is full of comments and debug output so you can see what is going on:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get background width and height
read wb hb < <(convert background.jpg -format "%w %h" info: )
echo "Background: " $wb $hb

# Get overlay width and height
read wo ho < <(convert overlay.png -format "%w %h" info: )
echo "Overlay: " $wo $ho

# Get wider of the two
w=$wb
[ $wo -gt $w ] && w=$wo
# Get taller of the two
h=$hb
[ $ho -gt $h ] && h=$ho
echo "New dimensions: " $w $h

convert background.jpg overlay.png -background none -gravity center -extent ${w}x${h} -composite result.png
```

[image]

Here is how it looks running:

```
Background:  300 50
Overlay:  122 242
New dimensions:  300 242
```

Presumably, when you have done your overlay, you would add `-trim` as the final part of the command line to remove any extraneous stuff that has been added.

Comment: Awesome! So simple. I'm on windows, so read wo ho < <(convert overlay.png -format "%w %h" info: ) wont work, but replaced it with equivalent DOS-style parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using convert rather than composite. It is more flexible than composite.

```
convert logo.png in_image.jpg -gravity center -compose over -composite out_image.jpg
```

But if you insist on using composite, then

```
composite in_image.jpg logo.png -gravity center -compose src_over out_image.jpg
```

Note sure exactly what you mean by preserving the alpha channel, since jpg does not support transparency. Perhaps you can post a pair of inputs and your desired output, if what I have posted does not do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, that does not work. The in_image.png simply gets pasted over logo.png. Also, if the in_image.png is larger than logo.png - the resulting image is cropped to logo.png dims (and of course, since the pasted image occupies 100% of that space, logo.png is not even visible anywhere, its been pasted over)

Comment: Can't edit a comment, but wanted to clarify that I am really looking for logo.png to sit atop in_image.jpg with alpha blending, while preserving the alpha on the logo.png

Comment: By preserving alpha, I mean that the final JPG will show an overlay of logo.png on top of JPG file such that the half-translucent areas of PNG file are blended on the JPG, JPG shows through clearly in areas where PNG is 100% translucent and JPG is completely obscured by areas on PNG that have no transparency.

Comment: In the future, please post example input and output images. It helps us understand better what you want.

Comment: I agree, typed up the whole e-mail with all examples - but my reputation limits my ability to post links or embed images. I could only post 2 with my question.

Comment: Did Mark Setchell's response answer your question? If not, perhaps post a comment or answer with your two input images as a follow-on to your question to help us understand and try to provide a proper set of code.

Comment: It did answer my question, and I marked it as answered along with "Awesome it works" comment. As I mentioned before, I cannot attach samples, due to my low reputation.